# Is it possible to avoid the black overlay when clicking links on Safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, outline

Is it possible to avoid the black overlay when clicking links on Safari on iPhone?

there is something like this for the web version of Safari

```
:focus {
outline: 0;
}
```

so can I avoid to see a black box when i click anything on a web page on for safari on iPhone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
```