# change colour of pressed button on mobile device

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

Is it possible to set with CSS / jQuery the colour a mobile device browser colours a button (e.g. `<a href>`) when tapped? e.g. on iPhone safari the  seems to be coloured 50% black - can I set the colour of this in anyway?

Comment: can you show us some code ? Or what you`ve tried so far?

Comment: Not tried much yet - its just a simple <a href> when tapped the mobile device colours the hit area of the <a href> in 50% black - Android devices seem to use light blue. Just wondered if there was a way in CSS to set this colour across all devices that's all

Comment: you can try adding styles to `a:active`

Comment: nope, :active :focus :down all don't change it

Comment: Question is still not clear. Which color do you mean? Do you have an image? maybe your problem is solved with: `outline:0;` on `:active`

Comment: Jan - any <a href> element - StackOverflow hid that from the original question - just updated it to make it appear!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone / css - how do I prevent black semi-transparent overlay on items when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178553/iphone-css-how-do-i-prevent-black-semi-transparent-overlay-on-items-when-cli) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106934/prevent-grey-overlay-on-touchstart-in-mobile-safari-webview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999006/is-it-possible-to-avoid-the-black-overlay-when-clicking-links-on-safari-on-iphon

Answer (score 0):

You may be searching for [appearance](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp):

```
button
{
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go - it wont work on Android devices though? Also just found this > <a href = "whatever0.html" style = "-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(200,0,0,0.4);">custom highlight color</a>

Comment: Android also uses webkit as the rendering engine, so it should behave the same. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it... This is the CSS one needs - seems to work on Android as well!

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(200,0,0,0.4);
```